# Unable to self test gmail action button markup, action button not showing up

Tags: gmail, google-schemas

I am trying to use Gmail email markup feature to have some convenient buttons alongside subject of the emails but i am unable to experience this feature working yet.

I am following a standard example to test this, using same email id as both sender and receiver.
Please let me know what is it that i am missing to get this awesome feature functional for my customers.
Please note that i havent registered yet as i want to test the feature first before trying to achieve this at any scale.

Here are the header info i see in original message option:

```
MIME-Version: 1.0
Received: by 10.28.153.23 with HTTP; Mon, 4 Dec 2017 11:20:46 -0800 (PST)
Date: Tue, 5 Dec 2017 00:50:46 +0530
Delivered-To: same.email.id123@gmail.com
Message-ID: <CAPQGoS6esH2HFWOFxFrYAwO8d=9Xn+2+nCiL9G7Gg986Xeq-
2Q@mail.gmail.com>
Subject: test-3
From: Blue Eagle <same.email.id123@gmail.com>
 To: "same.email.id123" <same.email.id123@gmail.com>
Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary="001a1145b9c08a20f4055f889d43"

--001a1145b9c08a20f4055f889d43
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="UTF-8"
 Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable
```

Below is the html i am trying with:

```
<!doctype>
<html>

<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<style type="text/css">
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    body {
        background-color: #FFFFFF;
        margin: 0px auto;
        padding: 0px;
        margin-left: auto !important;
        margin-right: auto !important;
    }
    table td {
        border-collapse: collapse;
    }
    [class=assetOff] {
        display: none !important;
        width: 0px !important;
    }
    [class=setDisplayWidth] {
        width: 380px !important;
    }
    [class=makeBlock] {
        clear: both !important;
    }
    [id=logoCell] {
        width: 111px !important;
    }
}
</style>
</meta>
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
        "@context": "http://schema.org",
        "@type": "ParcelDelivery",
        "deliveryAddress": {
            "@type": "PostalAddress",
            "name": "John Frank",
            "streetAddress": "24 Willie Mays Plaza",
            "addressLocality": "San Francisco",
            "addressRegion": "CA",
            "addressCountry": "US",
            "postalCode": "94107"
        },
        "originAddress": {
            "@type": "PostalAddress",
            "name": "John Frank",
            "streetAddress": "25 Willie Mays Plaza",
            "addressLocality": "San Francisco",
            "addressRegion": "CA",
            "addressCountry": "US",
            "postalCode": "94107"
        },
        "expectedArrivalFrom": "2027-03-10T12:00:00-08:00",
        "expectedArrivalUntil": "2027-03-12T12:00:00-08:00",
        "carrier": {
            "@type": "Organization",
            "name": "FedEx",
            "url": "http://fedex.com/"
        },
        "itemShipped": {
            "@type": "Product",
            "name": "iPod Mini",
            "url": "http://apple.com/ipad32gb",
            "image": "http://apple.com/images/ipad32gb.jpg",
            "sku": "B00DR0PDNE",
            "description": "iPod Mini 32Gb White",
            "brand": {
                "@type": "Brand",
                "name": "Apple"
            },
            "color": "white"
        },
        "trackingNumber": "3453291231",
        "trackingUrl": "http://fedex.com/track/3453291231",
        "potentialAction": {
            "@type": "TrackAction",
            "url": "http://fedex.com/track/3453291231"
        },
        "hasDeliveryMethod": {
            "@type": "ParcelService",
            "name": "http://schema.org/ParcelService"
        },
        "partOfOrder": {
            "@type": "Order",
            "orderNumber": "176057",
            "merchant": {
                "@type": "Organization",
                "name": "Bob Dole",
                "sameAs": "http://www.freebase.com/m/0fhkx"
            },
            "orderStatus": "http://schema.org/OrderInTransit"
        }
    }
</script>
</head>

<body align="center" style="margin:0px; padding:0px;-webkit-text-size-adjust: none;" bgcolor="#ffffff">
<table id="header" class="setDisplayWidth" align="center" style="margin-top:10px; padding-left:20px;padding-right:20px;" border="0" cellpadding="0" bgcolor="#ffffff" cellspacing="0" width="640">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td id="logoCell" class="makeBlock" align="left" height="100" valign="middle">.
  .
  .
  .
  .
</body>

 </html>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask What are you trying to do, what have you tried, and what results did you get.

Comment: Have you tried the [Apps Script Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/gmail/markup/apps-script-tutorial). It works for me and should demonstrate the concepts.